# C++: Combination of default parameters

Tags: c++, overloading, default-arguments

I have a function that takes up to 4 arguments, all of them optional. Also, all arguments have default values, and the user can specify whichever combination of arguments he wants.

So if I have this:

```
void func (const A &a = A(), const B &b = B(), const C &c = C(), const D &d = D());
```

The user can use it as `func(A(), B())` but not as `func(B(), C())`.

Is there any way to allow every argument combination without having to create a bunch of overloads? (In this case it would be 8)

Comment: named parameters idiom (aka the Builder Pattern), structs (especially in C++20 with designated initializers), [Boost Parameters](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) (or similar libraries)

Comment: I don't think it is there right now, `va_arg` allows a similar feature, but I am quite sure not the same. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/

Comment: This gets asked a lot, but I've rarely seen it asked with an actual real-world example where there wasn't a design problem. Perhaps you are different - in which case post miore details of your problem and design.

Comment: @Neil One good example is the std::set constructor. There you can pass either nothing, the Compare, the Allocator, or both. Now imagine that instead of just those two, you have potentially N.

Comment: @gmardau It's the imagining the case where you have potentially N that I have a problem with.

Comment: @Neil When I say N it doesn't mean infinity, but not just 1 or 2. Some other containers have an Equal and a Hash. You can very easily end up with more.

Comment: @gmardau You still haven't come up with a concrete case where you need this. which was the point of my original comment.

Comment: @Neil I just gave you an example with the set container. If you need a more clear picture, merge the two range constructors (2) into one. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set

Answer (score 0):

I have seen problems like this particularly when you're dealing with a big and old codebase. The best solution would be to redesign things so that you don't end up with such a problem, but I understand that sometimes you are under pressure and you have to make do with minimal changes.

For something like that, I would recommend creating a class that would encapsulate the parameters for that function. And that class would have the Builder design pattern:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

So that you would have flexibility in which parameters you would pass.

In the example you gave, you could have something like this:

```
class FuncParams
{
  public:
     A& getA();
     B& getB();
     C& getC();
     D& getD();

     class FuncParamsBuilder
     {
         FuncParamsBuilder& setA(A& a);
         FuncParamsBuilder& setB(B& b);
         FuncParamsBuilder& setC(C& c);
         FuncParamsBuilder& setD(D& d);
         FuncParams *build();
     }

     static FuncParamsBuilder& builder();
}
```

Then, your function call would be just:

```
void func(FuncParams *params);
```

And you could call it this way:

```
func(FuncParams::builder().setA(a).setC(c).build());
```

Notice that this is not a perfect way to code this: you should adapt the code snippets above to fit better what you're trying to do. You may also think if you want to use pointers, references, or, even better, smart pointers such as unique_ptr objects. I hope this helps!

Comment: Can't help noting that `func(a, B{}, c);` is a lot less typing and can use the original function.

Comment: That’s absolutely true. However, I thought that the point of this exercise was to *not* pass values to the parameters. If we pass values to the parameters, then we don’t even need default values: we can just pass values all the time.